# next-intl - how to connect with Crowdin JS SDK?

Tags: next.js, localization, internationalization, crowdin

There is a documentation page that recommends Crowdin as localization managment tool.
https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/localization-management

On the page there is an example with integration with github (automate making pull requests but using local files en.json ect).

But We are trying to figure out how to use next-intl with Crowdin JS SDK https://store.crowdin.com/crowdin-api-client-js, so we can download and integrate all translation from Crowdin dashboard and update them live.

Does anyone have an example code how to achieve that with next-intl?

We tried to found an example but did not found it on the documentation website

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to use the REST API for such cases (due to rate limits and security reasons). Use the [Crowdin OTA JS Client](https://crowdin.github.io/ota-client-js/) instead.

The Crowdin OTA JS Client provides methods to retrieve translation strings from JSON as objects or as plain text for other files. The main advantage here is the AWS CDN (Content Delivery Network) for translations, which provides low latency and high reliability for downloading translations.

For demonstration, I will use the [official next-intl example project](https://github.com/amannn/next-intl/tree/main/examples/example), and for fetching translations, I will use the [getStringsByLocale](https://crowdin.github.io/ota-client-js/api/classes/OtaClient#getstringsbylocale) method.

`src/pages/index.tsx`:

```js
import otaClient from '@crowdin/ota-client';
import {GetStaticPropsContext} from 'next';
import {useTranslations} from 'next-intl';
import LocaleSwitcher from 'components/LocaleSwitcher';
import PageLayout from 'components/PageLayout';

export default function Index() {
  const t = useTranslations('Index');

  return (
    <PageLayout title={t('title')}>
      <p>{t('description')}</p>
      <LocaleSwitcher />
    </PageLayout>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps({locale}: GetStaticPropsContext) {
  const client = new otaClient('<distribution-hash>');

  const messages =
    locale === 'en'
      ? (await import(`../../messages/en.json`)).default
      : await client.getStringsByLocale(locale);

  return {
    props: {
      messages
    }
  };
}
```

Please note that you will need to create a **Distribution** in your Crowdin project. Distribution is a CDN vault that mirrors the translated content of your project. Then use the distribution hash for the `otaClient` initialization.

- [Creating a distribution in crowdin.com](https://support.crowdin.com/content-delivery/)
- [Creating a distribution in Crowdin Enterprise](https://support.crowdin.com/enterprise/content-delivery/)

Here are the demos:

- [integrate Crowdin OTA Content Delivery into the example project](https://github.com/andrii-bodnar/next-intl/commit/96bd6621ce3725757b63db9ad4f3ac9ab4da5e89)
- [demo project in Crowdin](https://crowdin.com/project/next-intl-ota-demo)

Comment: Can you explain little more in details why "It's not recommended to use the REST API for such cases"? With next-intl and Next.js we can fetch translation files on server and add it to a Provider so it loads new files when you open a website. But also we can cache that response for some time so it does not refetch every time.

Comment: @TomislavKnežević it's possible to use API in case of fetching and caching translations on the server side and if making sure that the requests count will not grow alongside the traffic on the website. But it will be much slower than the CDN usage.

Comment: Have you ever use POEditor maybe? It also has an API but not the SDK. We already have it in our company as paid solution, so we are looking to not add one more paid product. But not sure it uses CDN...

Comment: No, I don't have any experience with POEditor

Comment: I encourage you to try Crowdin, I am sure you will like it